# Conditional probability find P(C)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

A and B are mutually exclusive events, and 
$P (A)=0.2$ and $P (B) = 0.8$ Find &P (AIC) when $P (CIA) = 0.4 $ and $P (ClB) = 0.5.  $

From $ P (CIA)  , P(C \cap A) =0.08$
From $P (CIB) , P (C \cap B) =0.4$
How can I find $P(C)$?

[image]

Comment: what is this $l$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $P(A)+P(B)=1$ and $A \cap B =\emptyset$ it follows that $$P(C)=P(C\cap A)+P(C \cap B)$$ $$=P(C|A)P(A)+P(C|B)P(B)=(0.4)(0.2)+(0.5)(0.8)=0.48$$

Comment: thanks but how do you know , $P(C)=P(C\cap A)+P(C \cap B)$? i mean why you not count the C part where is not in A or B?

Comment: $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)=1$ so $P((A\cup B)^{c})=0$. Hence $P(C \cap (A\cup B)^{c}))=0$

Comment: i still don t understand , is the picture like above? i know if A and B mutually exclusive the  $P(A \cap B) =0  $ but what is the relation with C?

Comment: There is only a set of probability $0$ outside of $A$ and $B$; in particular., the part of $C$ outside of $A$ and $B$ has zero probability.

Comment: because this $P(A)+P(B)=1$?

Comment: Yes, because $P(A)+P(B)=1$.